Multilayer RNN from scratch having input dilemma and inplace replace error during backprop in PyTorch
As per the definition of multilayer RNN, each time step's output from the first layer is used as input for the same time step of the second layer and so on Refer here.
However, in the implementation of RNN stated in PyTorch's official page RNN they are continuing to use the original input x[t] in all the layers for a given timestep. The code given below shows that in the layer loop.
RNN implementation as given in PyTorch's docs
def forward(x, h_0=None):
    if batch_first:
        x = x.transpose(0, 1)
    seq_len, batch_size, _ = x.size()
    if h_0 is None:
        h_0 = torch.zeros(num_layers, batch_size, hidden_size)
    h_t_minus_1 = h_0
    h_t = h_0
    output = []
    for t in range(seq_len):
        for layer in range(num_layers):
            h_t[layer] = torch.tanh(
                x[t] @ weight_ih[layer].T
                + bias_ih[layer]
                + h_t_minus_1[layer] @ weight_hh[layer].T
                + bias_hh[layer]
            )
        output.append(h_t[-1])
        h_t_minus_1 = h_t
    output = torch.stack(output)
    if batch_first:
        output = output.transpose(0, 1)
    return output, h_t

Would not it be something like this which I have written? The input in the 1st hidden layer should be the original input x[t] and then the input to 2nd hidden layer should be output of first hidden layer's output or h[layer-1] (with an affine transformation to make it size compatible with weights and biases). Refer to the code below.
My Implementation
def forward(self, x, h_0=None):
        batch_size, seq_len, _ = x.size()
        x = x.transpose(0, 1) #make sequence first for ease of computation
        if h_0 is None:
            h_0 = torch.zeros(num_layers, batch_size, hidden_dim)
        h_t_minus_1 = h_0
        h_t = h_0
        output_list = []
        for t in range(seq_len):
            #sequential latent space
            for layer in range(num_layers):
                if layer == 0:
                    current_input = x[t] if layer == 0 
                else 
                    current_input = F.linear(h_t[layer-1], self.w_hh2.T, bias = None)
                h_t[layer] = torch.tanh(
                                 current_input @ self.w_ih[layer].T  + 
                                 h_t_minus_1[layer] @ self.w_hh[layer].T + 
                                 self.b_hh[layer])

            output = F.linear(h_t[-1], self.w_oh, self.b_oh)
            output_list.append(output)
            h_t_minus_1 = h_t
        output_list = torch.stack(output_list).transpose(0, 1)
        return output_list


But unfortunately, my implementation gives inplace modification error while backprop.
RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation: [torch.FloatTensor [32, 128]], which is output 0 of AsStridedBackward0, is at version 68; expected version 67 instead.

at line containing
h_t[layer] = torch.tanh(
                                 current_input @ self.w_ih[layer].T  + 
                                 h_t_minus_1[layer] @ self.w_hh[layer].T + 
                                 self.b_hh[layer])


The code snippet is incorrect. For all layers after the first, the input to the nth layer is the output of the n-1th layer.
This is clarified in the num_layers section of the documentation:
num_layers – Number of recurrent layers. E.g., setting num_layers=2 would mean stacking two RNNs together to form a stacked RNN, with the second RNN taking in outputs of the first RNN and computing the final results. Default: 1

This is also consistent with the shape of the weights used:
weight_ih_l[k] – the learnable input-hidden weights of the k-th layer, of shape (hidden_size, input_size) for k = 0. Otherwise, the shape is (hidden_size, num_directions * hidden_size)

Layers after the first have a weight_ih_l[k] shape of (hidden_size, num_directions * hidden_size), which is incompatible with using the raw input.
I think this is just an oversight on the documentation. Under the hood, pytorch uses CUDA routines for RNN - the code in the documentation is not indicative of the actual implementation

I see this issue was recently reported at https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/129446
Note also that the example code has been modified to say output.append(h_t[-1].clone())
I'm also implementing the same basic code and seeing the same RuntimeError.
EDIT: So I fixed my RuntimeError and you've probably got the same issue.   If you follow the code for h_0 you'd think that it was a single tensor, like h_0 = torch.zeros(num_layers, batch_size, hidden_size).  However, if you do this then when you write to h_t[layer] you overwrite it so destroying the needed gradient information.  If h_0 is a list of tensors, then the old object persists and the gradient works.
